# Identifying point on Oracle mapView

Tags: oracle-spatial, identify

I developed an application depend on Oracle Map JS api v1, my application have multilayer, when I click on the map view all FOIs attributes should posted on a div; i.e: I need to identify a point like esri do.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you read the documentation before writing your code and that you looked at the tutorials that come with Mapviewer.

The default behavior for FOIs is that when you click on it, you will see a popup that contains the values of the variables (table columns) you have configured for that purpose in Mapbuilder. If that is not satisfactory, or if you want to customize the content of this "info window", then you need to register a listener that will fire upon clicking. You are then free to do whatever you like.

Again, this is all explained and illustrated in the documentation of Mapviewer's API and in the associated tutorials.